# Uniform detection: a starting point?

Tags: object-detection, object-recognition

Given an image of a worker, I need to verify if he/she is wearing the company's uniform.

I tried to Google, but either the search results are about uniform sampling or some object detection tutorials.

Might you help me to point out some starting points, ideally on some similar projects published somewhere?

Many thanks,

Comment: There are lots of image classification networks (ResNet, VGG for example) that allow this kind of classification if you have the according dataset. May you add details about the dataset you have (if you have one). Do you want to recognize multi people / just one person at a time ?

Comment: the pictures are taken by the selfie camera of the workers' drivers, not by our camera - so basically it can be anything. However, we want to recognize only one person at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You should take out the image embeddings of the uniform (under different conditions) and the employee and match the embeddings. You can also remove the face of employee after detecting it using MTCNN.

Comment: I am struggling to classify the problem. Is it an object recognition or object detection problem? Thanks.

Comment: It is an image similarity problem.